# Create an array of struct datatype from the join of two Hive tables

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, bigdata

I have two tables in Hive -

```
 emp(empid int,empname string,deptid string)
 dept(deptid string, deptname string)
```

Sample Data

Emp table in Hive has the schema empid int,empname string,deptid string

```
 1,Monami Sen,D01
 2,Tarun Sen,D02
 3,Shovik Sen,D03
 4, Rita Roy,D02
 5,Farhan,D01
```

Dept table in Hive has the schema deptid string,deptname string

```
 D01,Finance
 D02,IT
 D03,Accounts
 D04,Admin
```

I need to create another hive table which should have the following schema -

```
dept id string, dept name string, emp_details array<struct<emp_id:string,emp_name string>>
```

The array of struct attribute should contain all employee details - empid and empname belonging to a particular department and final dataframe should be converted to JSON format.

Desired output :

```
{"deptid":"D01","deptname":"IT","empdetails":[{"empid":1,"empname":"Monami Sen"}]}
{"deptid":"D02","deptname":"Accounts","empdetails":[{"empid":2,"empname":"Rita Roy"}, 
{"empid":5,"empname":"Rijul Shah"}]}
{"deptid":"D03","deptname":"Finance","empdetails":[{"empid":3,"empname":"Shovik Sen"},{"empid":4,"empname":"Arghya Ghosh"}]}
{"deptid":"D04","deptname":"Adminstration","empdetails":[]}
```

I need to use Spark version 1.6 and Scala 2.10 for coding. The datasets are huge hence would require efficient code handling for best performance.

Can you please help me with any suggestions for the code?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest performing a `left_outer` join, followed by a `groupBy/collect_list` aggregation and a `toJSON` transformation, as shown below:

```
val empDF = Seq(
  (1, "Monami Sen", "D01"),
  (2, "Tarun Sen", "D02"),
  (3, "Shovik Sen", "D03"),
  (4, "Rita Roy", "D02"),
  (5, "Farhan", "D01")
).toDF("empid", "empname", "deptid")

val deptDF = Seq(
  ("D01", "Finance"),
  ("D02", "IT"),
  ("D03", "Accounts"),
  ("D04", "Admin")
).toDF("deptid", "deptname")

deptDF.join(empDF, Seq("deptid"), "left_outer").
  groupBy("deptid", "deptname").
  agg(collect_list(struct($"empid", $"empname")).as("empdetails")).
  toJSON.
  show(false)
// +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |value                                                                                                                 |
// +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |{"deptid":"D03","deptname":"Accounts","empdetails":[{"empid":3,"empname":"Shovik Sen"}]}                              |
// |{"deptid":"D02","deptname":"IT","empdetails":[{"empid":4,"empname":"Rita Roy"},{"empid":2,"empname":"Tarun Sen"}]}    |
// |{"deptid":"D01","deptname":"Finance","empdetails":[{"empid":5,"empname":"Farhan"},{"empid":1,"empname":"Monami Sen"}]}|
// |{"deptid":"D04","deptname":"Admin","empdetails":[{}]}                                                                 |
// +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For `Spark 1.6`, consider aggregating via Spark SQL (as `collect_list` doesn't seem to support non-primitive field types in Spark DataFrame API):

```
deptDF.join(empDF, Seq("deptid"), "left_outer").
  createOrReplaceTempView("joined_table")

val resultDF = sqlContext.sql("""
  select deptid, deptname, collect_list(struct(empid, empname)) as empdetails
  from joined_table
  group by deptid, deptname
""")

resultDF.toJSON.
  show(false)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I implemented your solution but I got this error -:******×org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No handler for Hive udf class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFCollectList because: Only primitive type arguments are accepted but struct<empid:int,empname:string> was passed as parameter 1..;  **********         Collect_list can take struct parameter in spark 2+ but I am using v1.6. Can you please suggest any solution for this version?

Comment: @Monami Sen, please see my expanded answer.